# Hierarchical Explanation in iPython notebooks

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using iPython notebooks to explain a library that I'm working on that includes a lot of scientific background and examples by necessity.

Using the notebooks, I can embed code with comments and show it's results. But the amount of comments that are useful to a person depends on their background and their objective, so I don't want to slow down a user who just wants to skim, but I don't want to leave out a user who needs more in depth explanation.

So when I embed code, is there anyway to include some sort of markdown in the comments so that certain words can become tool tips? Do I have to build this myself using a [plugin](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/12/18/ipython-notebook-plugins/)?

For example, let's say I have the following code, with the extra explanation in curly braces.

```
# 10ms post-[synaptic]{the thing that connects neurons} filter
filtered = nengo.Probe(neuron, synapse=0.01)
```

When it's rendered in the notebook, you would be able to highlight the word `synaptic` and the explanation `the things that connect neurons` would pop up.

Comment: Since markdown allows arbitrary HTML, you could use an [<abbr> tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_abbr.asp).

Comment: @ThomasK does iPython natively support markdown in comments?

Comment: You can make markdown cells - there's a dropdown in the toolbar to switch between code cells, markdown cells and heading cells.